# Developer example for p2sh-multisig sees sendrawtransaction consistently return the "non-mandatory-script-verify-flag" error [Solved]

Tags: transactions, api, json-rpc, development, multi-signature

*Overview*

The following transaction: `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`

when passed to `sendrawtransaction()`, generates the following error:
`error code: -26
error message:
non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation) (code 64)`

The bitcoin source seems to suggest the transaction's rejected for being non-standard:
my transaction was based on the developer example at https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#p2sh-multisig which I thought would be standard, and the error occurs on testnet where I thought the related isStandard() checks are turned off.

**I am looking for insight into where I've managed to go wrong!**

*Detail: code, output, conf files, versions, transaction decode, redeem script decode*

I have rewritten the developer example as a self-contained bash script that resets regtest back to a known state then works through the snippets, or attempts to run on testnet. Where necessary, the calls have been adjusted to reflect API changes such as signtransactionwithkey vs signtransaction:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This code to implement p2sh-multisig example as worked through at
# https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#p2sh-multisig
#
echo "[Setting up run ...]"
DEBUG=true
USE_REGTEST=false  # If false, use testnet
ADDRESS_TYPE="p2sh-segwit"
BITCOIND_HOMEDIR="/home/bitcoind"
BITCOIND_CONFDIR=$BITCOIND_HOMEDIR"/.bitcoin"
if [[ "$USE_REGTEST" = "true" ]]
then
    AMOUNT0="49.99900000"
    AMOUNT1="10.00000000"  # Differs from example to forestall float and rounding issues
    AMOUNT2="9.99800000"
    REGTEST_PARAM="-regtest"
    REGTEST_DIR=$BITCOIND_CONFDIR"/regtest"
    BITCOIND_CONFFILE=$BITCOIND_CONFDIR"/regtest.conf"
    TEST_SPEND_FROM_NONCOINBASE=true  # Test if it matters that funds were generational
else
    AMOUNT0="49.99900000"  # Unused on testnet
    AMOUNT1="0.00030001"
    AMOUNT2="0.00015001"
    REGTEST_PARAM=""
    REGTEST_DIR="/dev/null"
    BITCOIND_CONFFILE=$BITCOIND_CONFDIR"/testnet.conf"
    TEST_SPEND_FROM_NONCOINBASE=false
fi
TXFEE="0.00013000"
BITCOIN_CLI="/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli -conf="$BITCOIND_CONFFILE" "$REGTEST_PARAM
BITCOIN_DAEMON="/usr/local/bin/bitcoind -conf="$BITCOIND_CONFFILE" "$REGTEST_PARAM" -daemon"
TEST_PUBLIC_KEYS_ONLY=true  # Public keys vs Addresses test

#
# Get regtest network back to a known state: stop if going, unlink regtest directories,
# restart, and generate first 101 blocks to get 50btc in funds. Give a short period
# to allow cleaning up etc. The 101 is important as it limits our balance to 50btc
if [[ "$USE_REGTEST" = "true" ]]
then
    $BITCOIN_CLI stop
    sleep 1
    rm -rf $REGTEST_DIR && $BITCOIN_DAEMON
    sleep 2
    $BITCOIN_CLI generate 101 >/dev/null
fi

#
# I see references such as at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/7277
# that one cannot send funds from coinbase to p2sh addresses over regtest.
# This code to send almost whole balance over such that a later spend to
# fund p2sh address cannot but come from a non-coinbase address
# Ignored on testnet
if [[ "$TEST_SPEND_FROM_NONCOINBASE" = "true" ]]
then
    NONCOINBASE_ADDRESS=`$BITCOIN_CLI getnewaddress $ADDRESS_TYPE`
    TXID=`$BITCOIN_CLI sendtoaddress $NONCOINBASE_ADDRESS $AMOUNT0`
    if $DEBUG
    then
    echo "Sending coinbase funds to new key"
    echo "[NONCOINBASE_ADDRESS]: "$NONCOINBASE_ADDRESS
    echo "[TXID               ]: "$TXID
    echo "-----"
    fi
fi

echo "[...Create and fund a 2-of-3 multisig transaction...]"
#
# Create the addresses we will use
NEW_ADDRESS1=`$BITCOIN_CLI getnewaddress $ADDRESS_TYPE`
NEW_ADDRESS2=`$BITCOIN_CLI getnewaddress $ADDRESS_TYPE`
NEW_ADDRESS3=`$BITCOIN_CLI getnewaddress $ADDRESS_TYPE`
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    # Example says addresses start with m, this code sees them start
    # with 2. Problem?
    echo "Creating new addresses:"
    echo "[NEW_ADDRESS1]: "$NEW_ADDRESS1
    echo "[NEW_ADDRESS2]: "$NEW_ADDRESS2
    echo "[NEW_ADDRESS3]: "$NEW_ADDRESS3
    echo "-----"
fi

#
# Obtain one public key - not sure why. To prove we can
# use either address or public key to create the
# multisigaddress? To show how to obtain the data for
# passing on to others? ("all of which will be converted
# to public keys in the redeem script.")
# NB: validateaddress in example superceded by getaddressinfo
if [[ "$TEST_PUBLIC_KEYS_ONLY" = "true" ]]
then
    RV=`$BITCOIN_CLI getaddressinfo $NEW_ADDRESS1`
    NEW_ADDRESS1_PUBLIC_KEY=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"pubkey": "//' | 
                      sed 's/".*$//'`  # Checked
    RV=`$BITCOIN_CLI getaddressinfo $NEW_ADDRESS2`
    NEW_ADDRESS2_PUBLIC_KEY=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"pubkey": "//' | 
                      sed 's/".*$//'`  # Checked
fi
RV=`$BITCOIN_CLI getaddressinfo $NEW_ADDRESS3`
NEW_ADDRESS3_PUBLIC_KEY=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"pubkey": "//' | 
                  sed 's/".*$//'`  # Checked
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    echo "Obtain public key per address:"
    if [[ "$TEST_PUBLIC_KEYS_ONLY" = "true" ]]
    then
    echo "[NEW_ADDRESS1_PUBLIC_KEY]: "$NEW_ADDRESS1_PUBLIC_KEY
    echo "[NEW_ADDRESS2_PUBLIC_KEY]: "$NEW_ADDRESS2_PUBLIC_KEY
    fi
    echo "[NEW_ADDRESS3_PUBLIC_KEY]: "$NEW_ADDRESS3_PUBLIC_KEY
    echo "-----"
fi

#
# Obtain the address and redeem script needed to obtain the funds.
# NB: createmultisig in example superceded by addmultisigaddress
if [[ "$TEST_PUBLIC_KEYS_ONLY" = "true" ]]
then
    RV=`$BITCOIN_CLI addmultisigaddress 2 '''
      [
       "'$NEW_ADDRESS1_PUBLIC_KEY'",
       "'$NEW_ADDRESS2_PUBLIC_KEY'", 
       "'$NEW_ADDRESS3_PUBLIC_KEY'"
      ]'''`
else
    RV=`$BITCOIN_CLI addmultisigaddress 2 '''
    [
      "'$NEW_ADDRESS1'",
      "'$NEW_ADDRESS2'", 
      "'$NEW_ADDRESS3_PUBLIC_KEY'"
    ]'''`
fi
P2SH_ADDRESS=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"address": "//' | 
           sed 's/".*$//'`  # Checked
P2SH_REDEEM_SCRIPT=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"redeemScript": "//' | 
             sed 's/".*$//'`  # Checked
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    echo "Obtain p2sh address and redeemScript:"
    echo "[P2SH_ADDRESS      ]: "$P2SH_ADDRESS
    echo "[P2SH_REDEEM_SCRIPT]: "$P2SH_REDEEM_SCRIPT
    echo "-----"
fi

#
# On regtest, send funds from the first 50btc block we can spend
# to the p2sh_address determined above.
# On testnet, send part of our balance
if [[ "$USE_REGTEST" != "true" ]]
then
    RV=`$BITCOIN_CLI settxfee $TXFEE`
fi
UTXO_TXID=`$BITCOIN_CLI sendtoaddress $P2SH_ADDRESS $AMOUNT1`
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    echo "Fund p2sh address"
    echo "[UTXO_TXID]: "$UTXO_TXID
    echo "-----"
fi

#
# Get everything thus far into a block
# $BITCOIN_CLI generate 1 >/dev/null

#
#

echo "[...Redeem the 2-of-3 transaction]"
#
# Obtain details about the funded transaction. We want whichever output
# was the 10btc output even though the example suggests there is only
# one output.
# NB: second parameter in example superceded after v0.14.0
RV=`$BITCOIN_CLI getrawtransaction $UTXO_TXID true`
UTXO2_VALUE=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"value": //' | sed 's/,.*$//'`  # Checked
UTXO2_VOUT=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"n": //' | sed 's/,.*$//'`  # Checked
UTXO2_OUTPUT_SCRIPT=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"scriptPubKey"//' | sed 's/"reqSigs".*$//' | 
              sed 's/^.*"hex": "//' | sed 's/".*$//'`  # Checked
UTXO1_VALUE=`echo $RV | sed 's/"addresses":.*//' | sed 's/^.*"value": //' | 
          sed 's/,.*$//'`  # Checked
UTXO1_VOUT=`echo $RV | sed 's/"addresses":.*//' | sed 's/^.*"n": //' | 
         sed 's/,.*$//'`  # Checked
UTXO1_OUTPUT_SCRIPT=`echo $RV | sed 's/"addresses":.*//' | sed 's/^.*"scriptPubKey"//' | 
              sed 's/"reqSigs".*$//' | sed 's/^.*"hex": "//' | 
              sed 's/".*$//'`  # Checked
if [[ "$UTXO1_VALUE" = "$AMOUNT1" ]]
then
    # Use first output (change is the second output)
    UTXO_VOUT=$UTXO1_VOUT
    UTXO_OUTPUT_SCRIPT=$UTXO1_OUTPUT_SCRIPT
else
    # Use second output (changes was the first output)
    UTXO_VOUT=$UTXO2_VOUT
    UTXO_OUTPUT_SCRIPT=$UTXO2_OUTPUT_SCRIPT
fi
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    echo "Capture which outputs we'll use:"
    echo "[1 VALUE            ]: "$UTXO1_VALUE
    echo "[1 VOUT             ]: "$UTXO1_VOUT
    echo "[1 OUTPUT_SCRIPT    ]: "$UTXO1_OUTPUT_SCRIPT
    echo "[2 VALUE            ]: "$UTXO2_VALUE
    echo "[2 VOUT             ]: "$UTXO2_VOUT
    echo "[2 OUTPUT_SCRIPT    ]: "$UTXO2_OUTPUT_SCRIPT
    echo "Vout and Output script chosen:"
    echo "[UTXO_VOUT          ]: "$UTXO_VOUT
    echo "[UTXO_OUTPUT_SCRIPT ]: "$UTXO_OUTPUT_SCRIPT
    echo "-----"
fi

#
# Now create the address redeemed to
NEW_ADDRESS4=`$BITCOIN_CLI getnewaddress $ADDRESS_TYPE`
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    echo "Create redeem-to address:"
    echo "[NEW_ADDRESS4]: "$NEW_ADDRESS4
    echo "-----"
fi

#
# Create a new transaction, slightly less value to accomodate mining fee
RAW_TX=`$BITCOIN_CLI createrawtransaction '''
   [
      {
        "txid": "'$UTXO_TXID'",
        "vout": '$UTXO_VOUT'
      }
   ]
   ''' '''
   {
     "'$NEW_ADDRESS4'": '$AMOUNT2'
   }'''`
RAW_TX_SZ=${#RAW_TX}
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    echo "Generate unsigned transaction:"
    echo "[RAW_TX]: "$RAW_TX
    echo "-----"
fi

#
# Get 2 of the 3 private keys
NEW_ADDRESS1_PRIVATE_KEY=`$BITCOIN_CLI dumpprivkey $NEW_ADDRESS1`
NEW_ADDRESS3_PRIVATE_KEY=`$BITCOIN_CLI dumpprivkey $NEW_ADDRESS3`
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    echo "Capture private keys for use in signing:"
    echo "[NEW_ADDRESS1_PRIVATE_KEY]: "$NEW_ADDRESS1_PRIVATE_KEY
    echo "[NEW_ADDRESS3_PRIVATE_KEY]: "$NEW_ADDRESS3_PRIVATE_KEY
    echo "-----"
fi

#
# 1 of 3 sign off the transaction
# NB: signrawtransaction in example superceded by signrawtransactionwithkey
# NB: order of parameters reverse, and amount becomes mandatory
RV=`$BITCOIN_CLI signrawtransactionwithkey $RAW_TX '''
    [
      "'$NEW_ADDRESS1_PRIVATE_KEY'"
    ]
    ''' '''
    [
      {
        "txid": "'$UTXO_TXID'", 
        "vout": '$UTXO_VOUT', 
        "scriptPubKey": "'$UTXO_OUTPUT_SCRIPT'", 
        "redeemScript": "'$P2SH_REDEEM_SCRIPT'",
    "amount": '$AMOUNT2'
      }
    ]'''`
PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"hex": "//' | sed 's/".*//'`
PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX_SZ=${#PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX}
if [[ $PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX_SZ -eq $RAW_TX_SZ ]]
then
    echo "Transaction didn't change size at PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX_SZ. Eh?"
    exit
fi
if [[ $PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX_SZ -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "Failed at PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX"
    echo "Response: "
    echo "[RAW_TX                  ]: "$RAW_TX
    echo "[UTXO_TXID               ]: "$UTXO_TXID
    echo "[UTXO_VOUT               ]: "$UTXO_VOUT
    echo "[UTXO_OUTPUT_SCRIPT      ]: "$UTXO_OUTPUT_SCRIPT
    echo "[P2SH_REDEEM_SCRIPT      ]: "$P2SH_REDEEM_SCRIPT
    echo "[NEW_ADDRESS1_PRIVATE_KEY]: "$NEW_ADDRESS1_PRIVATE_KEY
    exit
fi
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    echo "Transaction after first signature:"
    echo "[PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX    ]: "$PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX
    echo "-----"
fi

#
# 2 of 3 signs off the transaction
RV=`$BITCOIN_CLI signrawtransactionwithkey $PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX '''
    [
      "'$NEW_ADDRESS3_PRIVATE_KEY'"
    ]
    ''' '''
    [
      {
        "txid": "'$UTXO_TXID'", 
        "vout": '$UTXO_VOUT', 
        "scriptPubKey": "'$UTXO_OUTPUT_SCRIPT'", 
        "redeemScript": "'$P2SH_REDEEM_SCRIPT'",
    "amount": '$AMOUNT2'
      }
    ]'''`
SIGNED_RAW_TX=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"hex": "//' | sed 's/".*//'`  # Checked
SIGNED_RAW_TX_SZ=${#SIGNED_RAW_TX}
COMPLETE=`echo $RV | sed 's/^.*"complete": //' | sed 's/\W.*//'`  # Checked
if [[ "$COMPLETE" != "true" ]]
then
    echo "Second signature did not lead to completed transaction. Eh?"
    echo $RV
    exit
fi
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    echo "Transaction after second signature:" 
    echo "[SIGNED_RAW_TX]: "$SIGNED_RAW_TX
    echo "-----"
fi

#
# And now broadcast it
TXID=`$BITCOIN_CLI sendrawtransaction $SIGNED_RAW_TX`
if [[ ${#TXID} -eq 0 ]]
then
    echo "Broadcast has gone wrong. Eh?"
fi
if [[ "$DEBUG" = "true" ]]
then
    echo "TXID from broadcasting:"
    echo "[TXID]: "$TXID
    echo "-----"
fi
```

The code above generated the following output on the testnet run:

```
$ ./p2sh-multisig.sh
[Setting up run ...]
[...Create and fund a 2-of-3 multisig transaction...]
Creating new addresses:
[NEW_ADDRESS1]: 2NAWwgmSnPcXFshHX41ewLHaN4nYLTzEdHn
[NEW_ADDRESS2]: 2NAoFjMziphkxULu7p4dtcBKLXicnvvcX53
[NEW_ADDRESS3]: 2Mu3S24XuasYheQsinhKAabDnGnH6eakm2X
-----
Obtain public key per address:
[NEW_ADDRESS1_PUBLIC_KEY]: 036ef3ee62456676a49b3087df3f0d804eb09bfcfa95ca606465bee5cfeab4da98
[NEW_ADDRESS2_PUBLIC_KEY]: 0386518595790f10fa1915bb119a0b41d96a380eeb3f3a76ae0694acc9fd2fb333
[NEW_ADDRESS3_PUBLIC_KEY]: 0371d090dd98316a9f8f63c1d925b42cf157f265d1eff84b65620629914b43019c
-----
Obtain p2sh address and redeemScript:
[P2SH_ADDRESS      ]: 2N3G8rhzkMBmfRp54A4rfpW5jTcd65m7hCs
[P2SH_REDEEM_SCRIPT]: 5221036ef3ee62456676a49b3087df3f0d804eb09bfcfa95ca606465bee5cfeab4da98210386518595790f10fa1915bb119a0b41d96a380eeb3f3a76ae0694acc9fd2fb333210371d090dd98316a9f8f63c1d925b42cf157f265d1eff84b65620629914b43019c53ae
-----
Fund p2sh address
[UTXO_TXID]: 06c7e967e0d5f53899a02137d3a1d4dc0eee53690d20d403242954caa187c721
-----
[...Redeem the 2-of-3 transaction]
Capture which outputs we'll use:
[1 VALUE            ]: 0.00030001
[1 VOUT             ]: 0
[1 OUTPUT_SCRIPT    ]: a9146ddd64168434e4e7cf8f7a2a2b485fa1fc8f987e87
[2 VALUE            ]: 0.00005412
[2 VOUT             ]: 1
[2 OUTPUT_SCRIPT    ]: a9146ecbcb78f6ab60ebe53cc69532407a32973af9aa87
Vout and Output script chosen:
[UTXO_VOUT          ]: 0
[UTXO_OUTPUT_SCRIPT ]: a9146ddd64168434e4e7cf8f7a2a2b485fa1fc8f987e87
-----
Create redeem-to address:
[NEW_ADDRESS4]: 2MyuteHEFmxvG2rX8r817DTKhqj8f2ncsmt
-----
Generate unsigned transaction:
[RAW_TX]: 020000000121c787a1ca54292403d4200d6953ee0edcd4a1d33721a09938f5d5e067e9c7060000000000ffffffff01993a00000000000017a9144920d433d073267b904ae23df3b15ea47aec95038700000000
-----
Capture private keys for use in signing:
[NEW_ADDRESS1_PRIVATE_KEY]: cVT8F8PGF9HJSeBgQir5ZHj5Ng4upSPAJHyVnk2puYw6Zs5GdbyR
[NEW_ADDRESS3_PRIVATE_KEY]: cSakmVL2kdR5jTukCFNBPCifcmg3jjQ6eGEvtagnsAoSdDWcu4fT
-----
Transaction after first signature:
[PARTLY_SIGNED_RAW_TX    ]: 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
-----
Transaction after second signature:
[SIGNED_RAW_TX]: 0200000000010121c787a1ca54292403d4200d6953ee0edcd4a1d33721a09938f5d5e067e9c70600000000232200205d577278a6dfefffaa4e04ef23fd1172e923f9e7b4949f991b3d7f2af89abb83ffffffff01993a00000000000017a9144920d433d073267b904ae23df3b15ea47aec950387040047304402202c9946f1d50a974f3b7cf24a99002f3f3ca18af7b54939bf2ec1acf6f5528b07022029aaa63fde914735b8e92c202ce3d4b02ea8ded1d2b47821670dd3c6d8dcb02b0147304402201e5e933e674f7e4597c1066b48cdb4ca1c7382235b53d411608c2e3a22a31df7022022fc673d696987146effcbb9ce43265ab9ee19da05eaef0bb35ced729fe9592501695221036ef3ee62456676a49b3087df3f0d804eb09bfcfa95ca606465bee5cfeab4da98210386518595790f10fa1915bb119a0b41d96a380eeb3f3a76ae0694acc9fd2fb333210371d090dd98316a9f8f63c1d925b42cf157f265d1eff84b65620629914b43019c53ae00000000
-----
error code: -26
error message:
non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation) (code 64)
Broadcast has gone wrong. Eh?
TXID from broadcasting:
[TXID]: 
-----
$
```

The regtest and testnet conf files used (credentials redacted):

```
$ cat regtest.conf 
regtest=1
server=1
rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=xxx
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
deprecatedrpc=createmultisig
deprecatedrpc=generate
debug=1
[regtest]
rpcport=18443

$ cat testnet.conf 
testnet=1
server=1
rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=xxx
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=18332
```

The versions used:

```
Master:
Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.17.99.0-g6d0a14703e288d72ff19d4d89defbc853233899f
Bitcoin Core RPC client version v0.17.99.0-g6d0a14703e288d72ff19d4d89defbc853233899f
v0.17:
Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.17.1.0-gef70f9b52b851c7997a9f1a0834714e3eebc1fd8
Bitcoin Core RPC client version v0.17.1.0-gef70f9b52b851c7997a9f1a0834714e3eebc1fd8
```

A decode of the transaction:

```
{
  "txid": "e875677a43c3ea91f7ed5790f3133d130fdcbb9e0cc51f098971bb79517c7103",
  "hash": "8d0701cf48cbf48823ede2250832311cea93b6ea0ab116f9e6b4f40c64153027",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 372,
  "vsize": 182,
  "weight": 726,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "06c7e967e0d5f53899a02137d3a1d4dc0eee53690d20d403242954caa187c721",
      "vout": 0,
      "scriptSig": {
        "asm": "00205d577278a6dfefffaa4e04ef23fd1172e923f9e7b4949f991b3d7f2af89abb83",
        "hex": "2200205d577278a6dfefffaa4e04ef23fd1172e923f9e7b4949f991b3d7f2af89abb83"
      },
      "txinwitness": [
        "",
        "304402202c9946f1d50a974f3b7cf24a99002f3f3ca18af7b54939bf2ec1acf6f5528b07022029aaa63fde914735b8e92c202ce3d4b02ea8ded1d2b47821670dd3c6d8dcb02b01",
        "304402201e5e933e674f7e4597c1066b48cdb4ca1c7382235b53d411608c2e3a22a31df7022022fc673d696987146effcbb9ce43265ab9ee19da05eaef0bb35ced729fe9592501",
        "5221036ef3ee62456676a49b3087df3f0d804eb09bfcfa95ca606465bee5cfeab4da98210386518595790f10fa1915bb119a0b41d96a380eeb3f3a76ae0694acc9fd2fb333210371d090dd98316a9f8f63c1d925b42cf157f265d1eff84b65620629914b43019c53ae"
      ],
      "sequence": 4294967295
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 0.00015001,
      "n": 0,
      "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "OP_HASH160 4920d433d073267b904ae23df3b15ea47aec9503 OP_EQUAL",
        "hex": "a9144920d433d073267b904ae23df3b15ea47aec950387",
        "reqSigs": 1,
        "type": "scripthash",
        "addresses": [
          "2MyuteHEFmxvG2rX8r817DTKhqj8f2ncsmt"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The redeem script decodes to:

```
{
  "asm": "2 036ef3ee62456676a49b3087df3f0d804eb09bfcfa95ca606465bee5cfeab4da98 0386518595790f10fa1915bb119a0b41d96a380eeb3f3a76ae0694acc9fd2fb333 0371d090dd98316a9f8f63c1d925b42cf157f265d1eff84b65620629914b43019c 3 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
  "reqSigs": 2,
  "type": "multisig",
  "addresses": [
    "mpZQSfgndvkjqcoXdvofNsE3aJeRAXjrvM",
    "mz9eLLofqQKQcuhwGjHxxNhSVxvoYWZDrY",
    "mkZv5XqarsoFMoTWSgMfqE9yihvUu8AHAY"
  ],
  "p2sh": "2MxYTNmXWUFwv8miRAcoCsqAr7MduFCjEAV",
  "segwit": {
    "asm": "0 5d577278a6dfefffaa4e04ef23fd1172e923f9e7b4949f991b3d7f2af89abb83",
    "hex": "00205d577278a6dfefffaa4e04ef23fd1172e923f9e7b4949f991b3d7f2af89abb83",
    "reqSigs": 1,
    "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
    "addresses": [
      "tb1qt4thy79xmlhll2jwqnhj8lg3wt5j8708kj2flxgm84lj47y6hwps0je8zu"
    ],
    "p2sh-segwit": "2N3G8rhzkMBmfRp54A4rfpW5jTcd65m7hCs"
  }
}
```

Many thanks if you got down this far. You're great! Clearly I've misunderstood something. But what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in the `signrawtransactionwithkey` stage that your are setting the amount to be signed to be :

```
"amount": '$AMOUNT2'
```

If I followed your flow correctly, that is the amount that you want to *send* by redeeming the utxo.  If so, this is incorrect.  You need to sign the amount amount of the utxo itself (the one in the funding transaction).

Comment: @AlistairMann: You can accept the answer, however; click the check mark on the left.

Comment: Your answer is exactly right, and I'm sorry I'm not allowed to +1 you; the script now completes properly both on regtest and testnet. I'll elaborate beneath.

Comment: Good to hear!  Don't worry about the +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

@arubi has posted the correct answer, many thanks to him.

For anyone else in future, my mistake was in both the above `signrawtransactionwithkey()` calls where I used the amount I wanted to send FROM the p2sh address when the parameter requires the amount sent TO the address. On reflection this should have been obvious: all the other values in the second parameter are inputs, and I was adding an output.

I've uploaded the corrected code and the output from a regtest and testnet run to https://github.com/Csi18nAlistairMann/bitcoin-p2sh-multisig-example